# Why is this linear color gradient not moving? Trying to animate where color stops are in a gradient

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to make a linear color gradient "move" by changing the offset of the middle colorStop between values of .2 and .8.

In the code the middle color will move over to the right a little but then stop, sometimes glitching out the color.  I also have the value of the offset printing with the loop and it is staying within accepted values, but the middle color won't move back and forth.

Here's the code relevant to what I'm doing:

```
SetColorGradient: function() {
        TextGradient.addColorStop(0,"red");
        TextGradient.addColorStop(this.GradChangeOffset,"white");
        TextGradient.addColorStop(.8,"blue");
    },
    Update: function(modifier) {
        this.GradChangeOffset = this.GradChangeOffset + (this.GradChangeSpeed * modifier);
        //GRADIENT DEBUGGERS
        context.strokeText(this.GradChangeOffset.toFixed(2),canvas.width/2,canvas.height/2);
        //GRADIENT DEBUGGERS
        if (this.GradChangeOffset > .7 || this.GradChangeOffset < .2) {this.GradChangeSpeed = -(this.GradChangeSpeed);}
    },
```

Text.SetColorGradient is run, then Text.DrawText to actually fill the words, then Text.Update is run to change the GradOffset.  These methods are run once every iteration.

I'm assuming my problem lies somewhere in .SetColorGradient since my GradOffset is changing back and forth within the values I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot remove a color-stop from a CanvasGradient.

This means that after the first loop, you won't change your gradient in any way. It will be the same as a simple red:0 + white:0.2 + white:0.8 + blue:1.

To do what you want, you'll need to create a new gradient at every iteration:

```js
const ctx = c.getContext('2d');
let offset = 0.2;
let speed = .01;

function updateGrad(){
  offset = offset + speed;
  if (offset > .7 || offset < .2) {
    speed = -speed;
  }
  // you need to create a new gradient
  const grad = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, 0, c.width, 0);
  grad.addColorStop(0,"red");         
  grad.addColorStop(offset,"white");
  grad.addColorStop(.8,"blue");
  ctx.fillStyle = grad;
}
function draw(){
  updateGrad();
  ctx.fillRect(0,0,c.width,c.height);
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
draw();
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
```